# How to add undo-functionality to HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a Sketching app done in all HTML5 and Javascript, and I was wondering how I would create an Undo Button, so you could undo the last thing you drew. Any idea?

Comment: Checkout the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: why do you have java and objective-c in tags?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to store all modifications in a datastructure. Then you can delete the latest modification if the user wants to **undo** it. Then you repaint all drawing operations from your datastructure again.

Comment: Please see http://whiffdoc.appspot.com/tests/schema/diagram for an example of how to do this -- in this case by storing a JSON data structure representing the canvas information in an invisible DIV element.  (follow link on page to source)

Comment: @AaronWatters, this link directs me to 404.
Do you have the updated link?

Answer (score 3):

On http://arthurclemens.github.io/Javascript-Undo-Manager/ I have a working example of undo with a canvas element. When you make a modification, you feed the undo manager the undo and redo methods. Tracking of the position in the undo stack is done automatically. Source code is at Github.

Comment: I've fixed a couple of small drawing bugs in the demo.

Comment: This demo draws circles of various colors in Chrome and Opera, nothing if FF, and black colors in IE. Pretty strange. I'd love a follow up when this is fixed.

Comment: I have updated the demo URL so that it points to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

The other option, if you need to manipulate objects is to convert your canvas to SVG using a library that preserves the Canvas API preventing a rewrite.

At least one such library exists at this time (November 2011):
[SVGKit](http://svgkit.sourceforge.net/SVGCanvas.html)

Once you have SVG, it is much easier to remove objects and much more without the need to redraw the entire canvas.

Comment: Or he can just use canvas abstraction library, like [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/) to be able to work with objects on canvas programmatically.

Comment: Excellent @kangax. I'm curious, how do you think fabric.js would compare to SVGKit in terms of performance when it comes to editing objects in canvas with hundreds of nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure how it compares to SVGKit, but when it comes to large number of objects canvas tends to be more performant than SVG. Take a look at some benchmarks comparing Raphael (SVG-based) and fabric (canvas-based) — http://fabricjs.com/benchmarks/

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks but these compare to Raphaël only for static images which is obviously going to favor Canvas. Do you have any comparison benchmark with animations?

Comment: Nothing at the moment. I'll see if I can cook something up. Or maybe someone else will.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works for me. I have tried it in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome and it works really well in those two browsers.

```
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
var CanvasLogBook = function() {
    this.index = 0;
    this.logs = [];
    this.logDrawing();
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.sliceAndPush = function(imageObject) {
    var array;
    if (this.index == this.logs.length-1) {
        this.logs.push(imageObject);
        array = this.logs;
    } else {
        var tempArray = this.logs.slice(0, this.index+1);
        tempArray.push(imageObject);
        array = tempArray;
    }
    if (array.length > 1) {
        this.index++;
    }
    return array;
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.logDrawing = function() { 
    if (isFirefox) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL();
        this.logs = this.sliceAndPush(image);
    } else {
        var imageData = document.getElementById('myCanvas').toDataURL();
        this.logs = this.sliceAndPush(imageData);
    }
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.undo = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $('#myCanvas').width(), $('#myCanvas').height());
    if (this.index > 0) {
        this.index--;
        this.showLogAtIndex(this.index);
    }
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.redo = function() {
    if (this.index < this.logs.length-1) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $('#myCanvas').width(), $('#myCanvas').height());
        this.index++;
        this.showLogAtIndex(this.index);
    }
};
CanvasLogBook.prototype.showLogAtIndex = function(index) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, $('#myCanvas').width(), $('#myCanvas').height());
    if (isFirefox) {
        var image = this.logs[index];
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    } else {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = this.logs[index];
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
};
var canvasLogBook = new CanvasLogBook();
```

So every time you draw any thing you will there after run function canvasLogBook.logDrawing() to store a snapshot of the canvas and then you can call canvasLogBook.undo() to undo and canvasLogBook.redo() to redo.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you didn't depend on jQuery and if you get rid of the `isFirefox` boolean :)