# Disadvantage of multiple canvases for implementing undo/redo on a 2D context in a javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, undo, redo

Currently I have a singular 2d context/canvas for all lines drawn using lineTo(), but I wanted to implement an undo/redo function which isn't possible without redrawing the entire canvas again or saving states ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150610/undo-redo-for-paint-program-using-canvas), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099322/how-to-add-undo-functionality-to-html5-canvas)).

Compared to the other methods, is there a disadvantage to pushing a new canvas for each line drawn onto a stack? From a time complexity standpoint, undoing/redoing would be O(1) instead of O(n) but I'm not sure if there would be other issues.

Comment: The first link you posted pretty much explains that this approach is poor for memory and performance. You're still saving states with this approach, except the "state" is an entire canvas instead of just a few numbers in an array. Where do you arrive at O(1) here?

Comment: remember that every canvas takes width*height*4*8 bytes in memory only for the pixels' data. Let's say you have a 500x500px drawing area (quite small on a high-def monitor), every single canvas will take 8MB. Some OS (iOS) won't let you have more than a few pixel square total canvas area in your page, so in these OS, you will be able to save at most less than ten states.

Comment: @Kaiido this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido I don’t know anything about HTML canvases; why is each pixel 32 bytes? I would have assumed at least four (R, G, B, opacity)—what are the other 28?

Comment: @DaveNewton Red Green Blue and Alpha channels are all stored as uint8bits

Comment: @Kaiido That’s 4 bytes per pixel, or 1MB—what’s the rest for?

Comment: @DaveNewton Checking you're better awake than myself? You are entirely right of course

Comment: @Kaiido :) Checking my sanity—something I have to keep an eye on ;)

Answer (score 0):

As ggorlen and Kaiido mentioned, the disadvantage here is memory just like with saving previous states in other posts, since each canvas still takes up the entire canvas's size in memory.